# Java8 generic puzzle

Tags: java, generics, java-8, option-type

I'm using Java 1.8.0_151 and there is some code that doesn't compile and I don't understand:

```
Optional optional = Optional.of("dummy"); 
Optional<Boolean> result1 = optional.map(obj -> true);     // works fine
boolean result2 = result1.orElse(false);                   // works fine
boolean result3 = optional.map(obj -> true).orElse(false); // compilation error: Incompatible types: required boolean, found object
Object result4 = optional.map(obj -> true).orElse(false); // works fine
```

why it works fine on `result1` but gives compilation error on `result3`?
Additional info:

- In the first line, when I change `Optional` to `Optional<String>`, result3 is also able to compile
- When I break `result3` into 2 lines: like `result1` and `result2`, `result3` is able to compile

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: @AndrewTobilko may be the OP did that *on purpose*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Once you lose the type safety - it is lost for chained calls as-well. That is `Optional<Object> != Optional`. So when you do

```
 Optional optional = Optional.of("dummy");
 optional.map()
```

The `map` can only accept a raw `Function` and nothing else, which will return an `Object` obviously.

The correct way is to add type information :

```
Optional<String> optional = Optional.of("dummy");
```

Or you can cast unsafely:

```
boolean result3 = (boolean) optional.map(obj -> true).orElse(false)
```

Answer (score 4):

`optional` is a raw `Optional`, so `optional.map(obj -> true)` returns a raw `Optional`, and `orElse(false)` returns an `Object`, not a `Boolean`. The compiler doesn't know how to un-box an `Object` to `boolean`.

By changing

```
Optional optional = Optional.of("dummy");
```

to

```
Optional<Object> optional = Optional.of("dummy");
```

or

```
Optional<String> optional = Optional.of("dummy");
```

you will overcome this error, since now `optional.map(obj -> true)` will return an `Optional<Boolean>` and `orElse(false)` will return a `Boolean`.

Comment: I afraid `optional.map(obj -> true);` doesn't return a raw `Optional`, but `Optional<Boolean>` because the line:
    `Optional<Boolean> result1 = optional.map(obj -> true);`
works fine

Comment: @Henry actually a raw type can be assigned.to a generic type, so that assignment doesn't mean what you think it does.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers. I just want to give details on why it worked on `resutl1` but not `result3` on:

```
Optional<Boolean> result1 = optional.map(obj -> true);     // works fine
boolean result2 = result1.orElse(false);                   // works fine
boolean result3 = optional.map(obj -> true).orElse(false); // compilation error: Incompatible types: required boolean, found object
```

on `result1`, the `optional` variable was raw type, so `optional.map(obj -> true)` returned an `Optional` raw type.

When I declared `Optional<Boolean> result1`, `Optional` raw type was **automatically casted** to `Optional<Boolean>`
On the other hand, `optional.map(obj -> true).orElse(false);` failed because a raw type `Optional` object cannot call `.orElse(false)`

Another example of this behaviour with raw type is:

```
List li = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> li1 = li;
List<Integer> li2 = li;
List<Map> li3 = li;

li1.add("WWW");
li2.add(444);
li3.add(new HashMap());
```

will work fine for all scenarios, the `li` object will contain a String, an Integer and a HashMap(). The `li1, li2, li3` was automatically casted to non-raw type.